# Hyperlink between Apple Notes pages

Tags: notes.app, url

Is there a way to hyperlink within Notes, from one Note entry & back?

Comment: There's been several methods already provided in different answers.  Have you searched and tried those methods?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this, but one way to do this would be to share the note with yourself and use the iCloud link. Click the button to add people to the note, and choose the Messages option. Put in your phone number or email address. Then, open Messages and copy the link you just sent yourself. This link can then be used to open the note from anywhere.